# jQuery find next table row not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi created a table and which will allow users to insert multiple office numbers and addresses that are related to each. i.e Office One, Office Two etc.

I slidetoggle between these sections. I have 8 phone numbers and I use jQuery to hide ones that are not ticked and by clicking "add new number" it will reveal the next number in the list.

However as this only works on the section named office one and not office two. If you are able to click on add new number and test on office one and then office two you'll see the difference.

The jQuery I've used is as follows or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/6pcvk/):

```
    $(".add").click(function () {
        $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('.remove').remove();
            $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('.clearnumber').remove();
            $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').find('td:last').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Hide</a><a href='#' class='clearnumber'> Clear #</a>")
        });
    });
```

Any one know how I can make this generic to use on the next table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: closest() search for ancestors, .add button is not child of any '.contact_numbers' element.

Comment: @A.Wolff do you how I could make this a child? Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When click add, you are querying ".contact_numbers:hidden:first" from root.
So, the result from query is first contact_number from office one, because office one is hidden.

Before query .contact_numbers, query parent element of .contact_numbers in office two.
And I think you don't need to use closest on shown element.

```
$(".add").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.togglesettings').find(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
         $(this).find('.remove').remove();
         $(this).find('.clearnumber').remove();
         $(this).find('td:last').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Hide</a><a href='#' class='clearnumber'> Clear #</a>")
    });
});
```